# How to modify Content-Type in postman

Tags: postman, azure-logic-apps, webapi

I'm trying to test my logic app API in postman but I'm having an issue with header postman automatically adding

Content-Type = multipart/form-data;

when I hover on the content-type tab seeing this
"use the request body tab to control the value or remove the header"

Can anyone help me with how I can set Content-Type = application/json

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to untick that and manually add an header you want.

Comment: Hi Danny I tried to untick but postman automatically added when you click on send button below mentioned solution worked for me.

Comment: If you manually added a new `Content-Type: application/json` header, it would have used that. Going the route mentioned, would add that header too as it's matching the Content-Type to the body that you're using, for example `JSON` but you can add any Headers you like by manually typing them into a new field. 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to Body -> select raw -> Select JSON from the dropdown. It should look like the image below then set it to application/json

[image]

Comment: I am missing this option of "JSON" in my POSTMAN

Comment: @YuvalLevy I still see it on both mac and windows. Try install the latest version or use emery's answer

Comment: Make sure you click the "raw" option, then "JSON" will pop up

Answer (score 43):

Postman won't allow you to edit the headers that it auto-generates based on your drop-down selections, and Content-Type is one of these.

However it **will** allow you to **deselect** the auto-generated header and add a custom Content-Type header with any value you want.  As far as the actual request is concerned, that's equivalent.

[image: custom content type header in postman]

Comment: This should be the answer. I spent an hour trying to figure out what was wrong with my code. Postman wouldn't send the data to my API. Thanks.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde As time goes by Postman refuses to listen to what we want (like calling other requests from a test) and instead they decide to take a page out of Google's and Microsoft's playbooks and frustrate the crap out of everybody.

Comment: @MikeCheel I have to agree with you on that. Many simple tasks are absolutely complicated or hidden so well that you cannot help but pull your hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can go to Headers --->Presets-> Manage Presets [image]
and click on add to give your custom Header preset

[image: custom header details]

now you can see your custom Header , select to use it
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Taking the example of  the  auto-generated Cookie  header, if you would like to get rid  of it, just click on the  blue  Cookies  text (top-right), and  unselect all the  unwanted  cookies, and  the  cookie  header  will be  modified  accordinaly

[image]