# Callable https Firebase Cloud Functions via Postman: "Request has incorrect Content-Type. "

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to locally test my callable Firebase cloud function.

I understand that this needs to be a post request and that there needs to be a `Content-Type` of `application/json` and a data object in the body of the request.

Here is my raw body in the request:

```json
{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "data": {
        "aString": "some string",
    }
}
```

In the response body I get:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Bad Request",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

And in the terminal I get:

```json
>  {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Request has incorrect Content-Type. "}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Invalid request, unable to process."}
```

How do I format the body to get the right `Content-Type`?

#### Update:

Seems like the `Content-Type` used in Postman must be in the body and not the header:

[image]

The rest of the Postman request:

[image]

[image]

And my cloud function:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
const connectyCube = require('connectycube');

exports.createSession = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (context.auth) {
        const appId = functions.config().cc.appid;
        const authKey = functions.config().cc.authkey;
        const authSecret = functions.config().cc.authsecret;

        const CREDENTIALS = [
            {
                appId,
                authKey,
                authSecret,
            },
        ];

        connectyCube.init(...CREDENTIALS);

        const getSession = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connectyCube.createSession((error, session) => {
                if (session) {
                    resolve(session);
                }
                console.error('FUNCTION ERROR', error)
                reject(error);
            });
        });
        const session = await getSession();
        return session;
    }
    return new Error('App authorization error');
});
```

Comment: What does your cloud function look like? Also can you share a screenshot of your postman request?

Comment: In Postman where you see the bold, blue "Text" next to the GraphQL option, if you click that and select JSON, it will set the header for you. Right now, you're sending plain text and manually adding the header as a solution. Postman takes care of that if you choose the appropriate type for the raw body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answering but the reason this didn't work was because a custom header needs to be added in this specific way to the request in Postman:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68040185/11584105

Answer (score 0):

try moving `"content-type": "application/json"` this into header and request again.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammed, I've updated the question as it seems like you can only update the content-type in the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly call a Callable Cloud Function via an HTTPS request (instead of using one of the Client SDKs) your request needs to follow the [Protocol specifications for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) because "an `https.onCall` trigger for Cloud Functions is an HTTPS trigger **with a specific format for the request and response**".

Comment: Thanks - as far as I can tell I've already followed all the specifications in that document.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `application/json` in the headers and not in the body.
[image]

This should automatically change the header to `application/json` in the headers tab.
Please try switching to JSON from that dropdown menu and change your body to:

```
{
  "aString": "some string"
}
```